# jQuery Ajax multiplication

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, multiplication

I need your help please!
I want to multiply the quantity with the single price and put it in id called total using Ajax( I don't know Ajax well)

```js
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('.qty').on('keyup', function () {
        var singl_price = $(".single_price").val(),
            qty = $(".qty").val(),
            total_price = qty * singl_price;
            $("#total").text(total_price);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'cart.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: '',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === "ok") {                    
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
            }
        });    
    });   
});
```

```html
<form action="cart.php" method="post" >
  <input type="text" name="qty" class="qty" value="<?php echo $_POST['qty']; ?>" />
</form>

<div class="single_price"> 20 </div>

<div id="total"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$('.qty').on('keyup', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'cart.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {total_price:total_price},
            success: function (data) {
                   var total = 0;
                   $('.qty').each(function(i,v){
                   var singl_price = $(v).next(".single_price").text();
                   var qty = $(v).val().length > 0 ?$(v).val():0;

                  total +=  parseInt(qty) * parseInt(singl_price);
                  });
                  $('#total').text(total);

                if (data === "ok") {                    
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
            }
        });    
    });
```

html:

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post" >
      <input type="text" name="qty" class="qty" value="<?php echo $_POST['qty']; ?>" />
    <div class="single_price"> 20 </div>
    </form>



<div id="total">0</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o7hb7s6g/2/

Note:use parseFloat instead of parseInt if you have price with like 3.99

Comment: Nothing changed unfortunately :(

Comment: many thanks madalin ivascu, it works, but when I have more than 1 item in the shopping cart, it display all the total prices beside each others and every item take the same value that i put for 1 items...
EX : qty of 1st item = 2
single_price of 1st item  = 30
single_price of 2nd item  = 40
so it gives me total_price = 3040

Comment: Thanks madalin, and I'm sorry that I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer :) I have to have 15 reputation minimum.

Comment: you  can accept my answer if it answers your question

Comment: Ok I will, but I tried the last code it gives me NaN ??

Answer (score 0):

```
qty = $(".qty").val(),
```

Thats looking for an element with a class of qty, but you only have an element with a name of qty. You can add the `class="qty"` or try to look up using `$("[name=qty]")` which is a much slower selector. I would suggest reviewing jquery selectors

In addition, I'm not really sure what you are trying to do with your ajax code. If you are just trying to submit the form, `$('form').submit()` would work.

If you are trying to post, then:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cart.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { qty: qty }, // Data you want to submit
        success: function (data) {

            if (data === "ok") {                    
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
        }
    });
```